# Scroll on overflown sidebar instead of page behind

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is to have a background page fixed while sidebar should scroll down. Both of these elements are too big for the page. Normally page scrolls but when navbar is opened and is overflowing the height of the page then it should start to be scrollable. Take a look here:

https://jsfiddle.net/tpL92b01/2/

The grey div should be scrollable.

For demo purposed sidebar does not show and hide as it would typically.

```css
body, p, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p{
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}


.main-content {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

.sidebar ul {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.sidebar li {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="main-content">
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu item1</li>
        <li>Menu item2</li>
        <li>Menu item3</li>
        <li>Menu item4</li>
        <li>Menu item5</li>
        <li>Menu item6</li>
        <li>Menu item7</li>
        <li>Menu item8</li>
        <li>Menu item9</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add a max-height and overflow:auto to the sidebar, so it will have scroll only when needed.

```css
body, p, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p{
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}


.main-content {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar ul {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.sidebar li {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="main-content">
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu item1</li>
        <li>Menu item2</li>
        <li>Menu item3</li>
        <li>Menu item4</li>
        <li>Menu item5</li>
        <li>Menu item6</li>
        <li>Menu item7</li>
        <li>Menu item8</li>
        <li>Menu item9</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

just change this CSS

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
```